# Retreiving data from mongoose schema into my node js project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i am trying to retrieve my data from mongoose schema to my route ( say using an app named insomnia just like postman) so evertime i run the route i am getting and empty array, what is wrong with it ?

app.js

```
const express=require('express');
const bodyparser=require('body-parser');
const app=express();


app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
const User=require('./db/models/user').User;
require('./db/mongo');

app.get("/api/user",function(req,res){
User.find().then(function(x){
res.send(x)
console.log(req.body)
})
})







app.listen(3000);
```

mongo.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
db=mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/chatter_dev', 
{useNewUrlParser:true});
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open', function callback () {
console.log("h");
});
module.exports =mongoose;
```

user.js

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');


const userschema=new mongoose.Schema({
username:{
    type:String,
    unique:true,
    required:true
},
email:{
    type:String
},
firstname:String,
lastname:String},{
timestamps:true}
)
exports.User=mongoose.model("User",userschema)
```

Comment: Some basic check like do you have data in the table, is your code is connecting to the database...also share what is the output of ```console.log(x)```

Comment: @user269867 yup code connected as the line console.log('h') is showing up and console.log(x) gives []

Comment: can you add ```if(err) console.log(err)``` and the response?  also in user.js there is ```firstname:String,
lastname:String},{``` which doesn't look correct.

Comment: I think your code works just fine, maybe you should check you `require()` and  make sure you have data in your `users` collection.

Answer (score 1):

Before doing any work trying to get data OUT, ya gotta get a little data IN. Get into mongo and insert a few records manually. Baby steps can help you diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
 User.find((err, users) => {
    if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
    else res.json(users);
  });
```

Comment: still got nothing !

Comment: are you sure is data on your doucment?

Comment: well can u help me out how can i check it ? started mongo just today so was trying to connect it on the first attempt

Comment: try this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_query_document.htm hope this will help you

Comment: // Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(
    'mongodb://localhost::27017/chatter_dev',
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB successfully connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

Comment: ya it says succesfully connected

Comment: are you find the data??

Comment: again are you insert data in your collections?? other wise you flow this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_insert_document.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
**App.js**

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('./models/users');


const options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
};

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/chatter_dev', options)
    .then(connected => console.log(`Database connection establised`))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

app.get('/api/users', (req, res, next) => {
    User.find().then(user => res.send(user)).catch(err => console.error(err));
})

app.listen(3000);

**Users.js (model)**

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    username:{
    type:String,
    unique:true,
    required:true
    },
    email:{
    type:String
    },
    firstname:String,
    lastname:String
}, {timestamps: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```